# Correctly rendering a mirror in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, textures, physics

I have my code I wrote for displaying a mirror as a plane with a texture from a RenderTarget2D each frame.

This all works perfectly fine, but I still think that there is something wrong in the way the reflection goes (like, the mirror isn't looking exacly where it's supposed to be looking).

There's a screenshot of the mirror that doesn't really look bad, the distort mainly occurs when the player gets close to the mirror.

[image: Mirror Sample Image]

Here is my code for creating the mirror texture, notice that the mirror is rotated by 15 degrees on the X axis.

```
RenderTarget2D rt;
```

...

```
rt = new RenderTarget2D(device, (int)(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth * 1.5), (int)(graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight * 1.5));
```

...

```
device.SetRenderTarget(rt);
device.Clear(Color.Black);

Vector3 camerafinalPosition = camera.position;
if (camera.isCrouched) camerafinalPosition.Y -= (camera.characterOffset.Y * 6 / 20);

Vector3 mirrorPos = new Vector3((room.boundingBoxes[8].Min.X + room.boundingBoxes[8].Max.X) / 2, (room.boundingBoxes[8].Min.Y + room.boundingBoxes[8].Max.Y) / 2, (room.boundingBoxes[8].Min.Z + room.boundingBoxes[8].Max.Z) / 2);

Vector3 cameraFinalTarget = new Vector3((2 * mirrorPos.X) - camera.position.X, (2 * mirrorPos.Y) - camerafinalPosition.Y, camera.position.Z);
cameraFinalTarget = Vector3.Transform(cameraFinalTarget - mirrorPos, Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(-15))) + mirrorPos;

Matrix mirrorLookAt = Matrix.CreateLookAt(mirrorPos, cameraFinalTarget, Vector3.Up);

room.DrawRoom(mirrorLookAt, camera.projection, camera.position, camera.characterOffset, camera.isCrouched);

device.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

And then the mirror is being drawn using the `rt` texture.
I supposed something isn't completly right with the reflection physics or the way I create the LookAt matrix, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use XNA, but I did some Managed C# DX long time ago, so I don't remember too much, but are you sure `mirrorLookAt` should point to a cameraFinalTarget? Because basically the `Matrix.CreateLookAt` should create a matrix out of from-to-up vectors - 'to' in your example is a point where mirror aims. You need to calculate a vector from camera position to mirror position and then reflect it, and I don't see that in your code.

Unless your `room.DrawRoom` method doesn't calculate another `mirrorLookAt` matrix, I'm pretty sure your mirror target vector is the problem.

**edit:** Your reflection vector would be

```
Vector3 vectorToMirror = new Vector3(mirrorPos.X-camera.position.Y, mirrorPos.Y-camera.position.Y, mirrorPos.Z-camera.position.Z);
Vector3 mirrorReflectionVector = new Vector3(vectorToMirror-2*(Vector3.Dot(vectorToMirror, mirrorNormal)) * mirrorNormal);
```

Also I don't remember if the mirrorReflectionVector shouldn't be inverted (whether it is pointing to mirror or from mirror). Just check both ways and you'll see. Then you create your `mirrorLookAt` from

```
Matrix mirrorLookAt = Matrix.CreateLookAt(mirrorPos, mirrorReflectionVector, Vector3.Up);
```

Though I don't know wher the normal of your mirror is. Also, I've noticed 1 line I can't really understand

```
if (camera.isCrouched) camerafinalPosition.Y -= (camera.characterOffset.Y * 6 / 20);
```

What's the point of that? Let's assume your camera is crouched - shouldn't its Y value be lowered already? I don't know how do you render your main camera, but look at the mirror's rendering position - it's way lower than your main eye. I don't know how do you use your `IsCrouched` member, but If you want to lower the camera just write yourself a method `Crouch()` or anything similar, that would lower the Y value a little. Later on you're using your `DrawRoom` method, in which you pass `camera.position` parameter - yet, it's not "lowered" by crouch value, it's just "pure" camera.position. That may be the reason it's not rendering properly. Let me know If that helped you anything.

Comment: Although this may have been done wrong, `cameraFinalTarget` (that I should have called `mirrorTarget`) is basically the position of the camera, but inverted by the mirror position by both X and Y axes (`(2 * mirrorPos.X) - camera.position.X` is actually `mirrorPos.X - (camera.position.X - mirrorPos.X)`, and same for the Y axis).

Comment: Where did you get that from? You're supposed to use dot product to calculate a proper reflected vector. It's V−2(V dot n) n, where n is normalised normal vector of your mirror.

Comment: You may also need to negate the reflection vector, depending on which way did you note your V (from or to the mirror's surface).

Comment: Thought about it myself, I couldn't find anything on the internet.
Anyway, how do I translate `V−2(V dot n) n` to actual code? Could you edit your main answer? Thanks

Comment: About that crouching line, for some reason I don't quite remember I didn't get the crouching into the actual position, but had it calculated by itself before it's needed.